# Physical Cause of Reactance of Inductors and Capacitors

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

We know that a capacitor and an inductor both offer some opposition to the flow of current through an AC circuit and their reactance is a measure of the amount of Ohmic opposition due to these circuit components. I am aware of how these quantities arise mathematically. However, my question is, physically why do these circuit components provide a type of opposition to current flow in the case of AC circuits? What is the *actual* cause for this reactance to appear?

Comment: Not ohmic opposition. Ideal inductor or ideal capacitor does not have ohmic resistance.

Comment: @JánLalinský, but see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance. A version of Ohm's Law using complex numbers can be used to describe the behaviors of capacitors, inductors, and resistors in a network that is driven by a pure sinusoidal source.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes there is formal similarity, because the relation is linear. But that does not imply there is ohmic resistance.

Comment: I guess I was thinking that "Ohmic" could be understood in more than one way; (1) as a physical mechanism, or (2) as a mathematical model. Perhaps a physicist naturally would think of (1). I have spent most of my career working closely with electrical engineers, and so I was maybe misled to think of (2).

Comment: @SolomonSlow ohmic resistance does refer to a mathematical model, $I=\mathscr{E}/(r+R)$, or its local version, $\mathbf j = \sigma \mathbf E$. These models do not capture behaviour of perfect inductor or capacitor. $U=ZI$ with complex $Z$ is also linear model, but I would not call it ohmic.

Comment: From *"[Electrical reactance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance)"* (my emphasis): *"reactance is the opposition presented to alternating current by* ***inductance and capacitance***. *Along with* ***resistance***, *it is one of two elements of impedance; however, while both elements involve transfer of electrical energy, no dissipation of electrical energy as heat occurs in reactance;"*

Comment: *[ohmic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ohmic#Adjective)* - *"1. Of or relating to, or measured in, ohms. 2. That obeys Ohm's law"*

Comment: From *"[Electrical resistance and conductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance)"*: *"The electrical resistance of an object is a measure of its opposition to the flow of electric current."*

Comment: Conclusion? Possible conflation of terms.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In a circuit the battery does work on the electrons passing through it, and this increases the energy of the electrons. Then in a resistor that energy is converted to heat as the electrons collide with atoms in the resistor and transfer energy to them.

So *resistance* is the loss of energy of the electrons as their energy is converted to other forms. In a resistor this other form is just heat and the energy is lost for good.

In an inductor the energy of the electrons is converted to the energy of a magnetic field inside and around the inductor. In a capacitor the energy of the electrons is converted to the energy of an electric field between the plates of the capacitor. In both cases this appears as a *resistance* because the electrons are losing energy. However in an inductor and capacitor the energy can be transferred back to electrons when the polarity changes, so the energy is only stored temporarily and not lost completely.

Answer (score 4):

To add to @JohnRennie's answer.

An analogy which is often used is between a mechanical spring-mass system and an electrical inductor-capacitor system.

In the mechanical system the mass can be thought of capable of storing kinetic energy whereas the spring stores potential energy and when the system is oscillating there is a interchange between these two types of energy.

In the electrical system the inductor can be thought of capable of storing magnetic field energy as a result of a current (moving charges) passing through the inductor whereas the capacitor stores electric potential energy and when the system is oscillating there is a interchange between these two types of energy.

The analogy goes further in that for the electrical case charge, rate of flow of charge (electric current) and rate of change of current replace displacement, velocity and acceleration in the mechanical case.

Thus a mass "resists" a change in velocity, $F=m\frac{dv}{dt}$, and an inductor "resists" a change of current, $\mathcal E = L\frac{dI}{dt}$.

A spring produces a force which can do work when it is extended, $F=kx$, and a capacitor has a voltage across its plates which can do work when charge is stored on it, $V=\frac 1C Q$.